# Make Angular use absolute URL in href and src

Tags: angular, url, path

If I view the source of my Angular page in the browser I can see that css links are automatically getting the following format:

```
<link href="styles.ab78b8ab75a65b5b6.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

On some pages I need the full path to be included, like this:

```
<link href="https://example.com/styles.ab78b8ab75a65b5b6.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

How can I achieve this?
Note that the current format should still be default. I need to be able to only include the full path on some specific pages. I need this both for link src (css) and script href.

Comment: have your tried putting in the complete link, they should work the way you want them to right out of the box

Comment: @Minato The css link tags are automatically inserted by Angular so I do not know if I can just change to complete absolute url's in some way, but that may not be good because I just want absolute url's on a few pages and not on other pages.